# R: Select each 10 random entries from a column based on values in other column

Tags: r, sample

Apologies if this has been asked before - i did use the Search function.

Variable X has 1-100 categories with a variable number of rows per category (all above 10). Variable Y has values associated with each X. How can I extract a random subsample of Y with each 10 Y per X? The goal is to reduce the total amount of data in the file (right now it has 11000 rows, ideally with the output of a binary coded column Z to include/exclude cases (where Z is assigned to random 10 Y's of each category X.

It should be fairly easy I guess?

Regards, 
KCW

Comment: I did a quick search and couldn't find an obvious match, either. I share your your suspicion that something similar has been asked before but maybe not with the request to have an indicator column constructed.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy to do with a combination of the `sample` and `ave` functions:

```
dfrm$Z <- ave(dfrm$X, dfrm$X, FUN= 
             function(x) sample(c( rep(TRUE,10), rep(FALSE, length(x)-10))) )
dfrm[dfrm$Z , "Y"]
```

Within each category of X, sample will return a logical vector with 10 TRUEs and the rest FALSEs that have been permuted, because that is the behavior of `sample` when no second length argument is given. This leaves behind the Z columns so you could do other tests on the `FALSE`-Z's. The first argument to `ave` is basically ignored and thrown away. Its only real purpose is to provide a vector whose length is used in the construction of the logical return value.

When building a function for `ave` it's useful to imagine what should be returned that will be the same length and in the proper order to line up with the items in just one selection of X within a single category of the grouping variables. Because the grouping variables are entered as triple-dot items you always need to specify the "FUN=" or you get inscutable error messages.

Comment: I've got to figure out `ave`. +1.

Comment: You need `ave` whenever you want to append a variable columnwise to a dataframe that involves grouping and anything other than simple columnwise numerical operations. You can label the first n entries, get `min`'s and `max`'s or other within-group operations.  Unlike `tapply` it always returns a vector of the same length as its first argument.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and your edit. Both are useful for helping me understand `ave` a little bit better.

Comment: Thank you all, that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`plyr`](http://plyr.had.co.nz/), it's a one-liner:

```
df <- data.frame(x=rep(1:10, times=1000),y=1:10000)
ddply(df, "x" , function(df) df[sample(nrow(df), 10),])
```

Your logical vector might be a little more complicated, following the same principle I'd

```
ddply(df, "x" , function(df) { 
    pick <- rep(FALSE,nrow(df)); 
    pick[sample(nrow(df),10)] = TRUE; 
   cbind(df, "z"=pick) 
})
```

Fairly sure that can be improved upon though.

Answer (score 0):

Because of how R works, this would probably be a very fast option.

First, some sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10, times = sample(10:30, 10)))
dat$y <- rnorm(nrow(dat))
```

Then, create a `z` variable with all values `FALSE`.

```
dat$z <- FALSE
```

Use `rle` and `cumsum` to figure out your samples, subset those, and mark them as `TRUE`.

```
RLE = c(1, cumsum(rle(dat$x)$lengths))
dat$z[c(sapply(1:(length(RLE)-1), 
           function(x) sample(RLE[x]:RLE[x+1], 10)))] <- TRUE
```

### Benchmarks, anyone?

Using the sample data in this post, here's a comparison of DWin's solution, themel's solution, this basic subsetting solution, and two other options from base R:

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(BY = do.call(rbind, 
                       by(dat, dat$x,
                          FUN = function(i) { 
                            i$z <- FALSE; 
                            i[sample(nrow(i), 10), "z"] <- TRUE; 
                            i })), 
          LAPPLY = do.call(rbind, 
                           lapply(split(dat, dat$x), 
                                  FUN = function(i) { 
                                    i$z <- FALSE;
                                    i[sample(nrow(i), 10), "z"] <- TRUE;
                                    i })), 
          SUBSET = { 
            RLE = c(1, cumsum(rle(dat$x)$lengths));
            dat$z <- FALSE; 
            dat$z[c(sapply(1:(length(RLE)-1),
                           function(x) 
                             sample(RLE[x]:RLE[x+1], 10)))] <- TRUE },
          DDPLY = ddply(df, "x" , function(df) {
            pick <- rep(FALSE,nrow(df));
            pick[sample(nrow(df),10)] = TRUE; 
            cbind(df, "z"=pick) 
          }), 
          AVE = { dat$z <- FALSE; 
                  ave(dat$x, dat$x, 
                      FUN=function(x) 
                        sample(c(rep(TRUE, 10), rep(FALSE, length(x)-10))))},
          columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", 
                      "relative", "user.self"),
          order = "relative")
#     test replications elapsed   relative user.self
# 3 SUBSET          100   0.044   1.000000     0.044
# 5    AVE          100   0.078   1.772727     0.080
# 2 LAPPLY          100   0.601  13.659091     0.600
# 1     BY          100   0.675  15.340909     0.680
# 4  DDPLY          100   6.016 136.727273     6.008
```